# Port 443 blocked by Firewall in Ubuntu 14.04 hosted on Azure

Tags: azure, https, port, ubuntu-14.04, firewall

I have hosted my website on Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine using Ubuntu 14.04.

I am trying to open Port 443 in Endpoints on Azure Portal.

But the firewall is blocking it.

I tried to open it through the firewall but its still showing as closed.

Can someone guide me as to what I need to do in order to open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Server Configuration was wrong because of which i was not able to open the PORT 443. Nothing was blocked from firewall or Azure. If anyone facing the same problem then first be sure about your Server settings then firewall and in the end you need to enable PORT 443 in the Azure portal. Hope it will help others as well or let me know...

Answer (score 0):

You can it open with command: `sudo ufw allow 443/tcp`
What is the output of the `nmap host` command?

Comment: I have already tried using that command but its not working. Output of nmap localhost is PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
631/tcp  open  ipp
3306/tcp open  mysql
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
5910/tcp open  cm
5911/tcp open  cpdlc